# MySQL and Form with equation

Tags: html, mysql, equation

I have a Form that looks like this:

```
Section              | Length   | Number 

Dropdown of sections | Integer  | Integer
```

Then I have a SQL that looks like this

```
Section (List of sections) | Weight (Weight of section) | Cost (Cost of section)
```

The user will chose the section from the dropdown, enter the number of the section required and the length of the section. The user will then click a button to add the data to a table underneath the form.

On click I need the chosen section's length multiplied by number then multiplied by weight, and chosen section's length multiplied by number and then by cost. Which will then be displayed in a table like this

```
Section    | Total Length | Weight | Cost 

152x152x25 | 5000         | 25     | 600
```

It must be able to add quite a few entries to the table.

Sadly, I'm a designer and not a programmer, so if I could get some help, I would really appreciate it.

*edit*

1. The answers I used (152x152x25|5000|25|600) are just an example.
2. I'm going to use a normal Linux server to deliver an HTML page containing the form and the table. There will then be a "Print" to print the table and "Send" to email the table. I plan on populating the SQL database myself.

Comment: Can you please show the entries that should be inserted for this entry you showed `152x152x25 | 5000         | 25     | 600 `?

Comment: Tell us more about your environment, especially the middleware/application server.